# "Reset Password" for facebook authenticated user in parse

Tags: parse-platform

When a user that usually authenticates with his facebook account and tries to run the "Reset Password" operation, he gets an email and can reset his password (which is clearly doesn't make sense because he does not have a password).

I guess it is just a bug in the "Reset Password" operation, but just to make sure, did it happen to anyone else?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming

Answer (score 2):

Technically there is a password... and an app can allow a user authenticated via FB to set the username and password properties for their User object, giving them multiple avenues for logging in.

Fair point that we can likely identify this scenario and prompt the user to log in via Facebook.